# How to get the index of a specific div based on class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have *N* divs with the class "item". When i click (or hover) one of them.. i would like to get the index based on the class so **index()** doesn't works for me because it's based on the parent element.

I'm looking for something like **eq()** but in reverse.

Comment: Show your code We didn't imagine your description??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.index()` without any argument will only work when all of them are sibling elements of each other. You should rather get object of all `.item` elements and then find current elements index by passing current elements context as argument to index method:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
   var currentelemnindex = $('.item').index(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `indexOf()` for that purpose:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.